# Is there a way to reuse the output of the Optics algorithm for Optics Xi in ELKI?

Tags: elki, optics-algorithm

I'm using elki with the gui and the command line and I want to use the Optics Xi algorithm with the same minPts value but different Xi values multiple times. So as far as I understand Optics Xi it should not be necessary to run the normal Optics algorithm more than once to calculate the clusters with different Xi parameters. 
Is there a way to reuse the reachability distances from Optics for the Optics Xi calculations in elki?

Comment: Use the source code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not on command line / MiniGUI as of now. `OPTICSXi` is implemented as a wrapper around an `OPTICSTypeAlgorithm`, because then people don't forget to first run `OPTICS`, before adding `OPTICSXi`

But this is trivial to do using the source code, since `OPTICSXi` does not change the OPTICS result. Just make the `extractClusters` method `public` and call it on the existing `ClusterOrder`.

To make this possible to use from command line / MiniGUI, you could do a stub `OPTICSTypeAlgorithm` algorithm that simply "reuses" an existing OPTICS cluster order.